Twillio gather is taking too long
I have made a program where user can talk to ChatGPT by using Twillio and google speech to text.
I want to be able to use Twillio built-in speech-to-text by using gather because built in stuff works faster. Now my web socket first needs to send microphone as stream and then send transcription back but this just takes long time and I would like to eliminate it :
I will have to send an ai response and then also allow user to speak and continue the transcribing again. but it is just taking too long.
  response.gather({
                    input: 'speech',
                    speechModel: 'google_cloud_v2',
                    language: 'nl-NL',
                    speechTimeout: "auto",
                    timeout: 2,
                    action: `${ngrokUrlClient}/Twillliotranscribe`,
                    method: 'POST'
                });

I do check and I get the transcription very quickly but it only once I try to send the transcription and establish connection. SO this is the part where it goes wrong. : "the part of sending ai response and then opening microphone so user can talk again"
try {
        const VoiceResponse = twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;
        const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
    
        // twiml.say({ language: 'nl-NL', voice: TwillioVoice }, aiResponse);
        twiml.say({ language: 'nl-NL', voice: TwillioVoice }, aiResponse);
    
        if (TwillioTTS) {
    
            twiml.say({ language: 'nl-NL', }, "Talk now ");
    
            twiml.gather({
                input: 'speech',
                speechModel: 'google_cloud_v2',
                language: 'nl-NL',
                speechTimeout: "auto",
                timeout: 2,
                action: `${ngrokUrlClient}/Twillliotranscribe`,
                method: 'POST'
            });
    
            await activateStream(twiml, CallerID)
    
        }
        if (!TwillioTTS) {
            await activateStream(twiml, CallerID)
        }
    
        // Update the call using Twilio's API
        const call = await client
            .calls(CallerID)
            .update({ twiml: twiml.toString() });
    
        logTwiml = twiml.toString();
        console.log("Twiml structure =" + logTwiml)
    
        console.log("Twiml response =" + call)
        // stopwatch
        await stopStopwatchTwillioresponse()
        await stopStopwatch()

the problem is that this will take more then 10 seconds until I get a response.
when I was using my WebSocket server it would be done within 4-5 seconds:
async function activateStream(response, Callid) {
        try {
            response.say({ language: 'nl-NL' }, " Talk now");

            // Construct the WebSocket URL from the ngrok URL
            const websocketUrl = ngrokUrlWebsocket.replace('http', 'ws') + '/ws';
            console.log(`WebSocket URL: ${websocketUrl}`);
            const connect = response.connect();
            connect.stream({
                url: websocketUrl,
                parameters: { CallerID: `${Callid}` }
            });
            console.log("klaar verbindin stream")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

My question is if anyone knows how I can reduce the delay because something is wrong where when opening a new stream en allow user to speak again.
so the transcription time has nothing to do with it only the opening new stream part.
How can I solve this or do I just need to keep using my websocket server.
I tried changing Timout and speachtimout settings. Also i tried using a regular post instead of a function but that did also not do anything.
Also i tried removing the .say to see if it would do anyhting but it didnt do anything.
